# Query posts with specific Taxonomy first

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, posts

I'm trying to query posts in wordpress, so far so good. However, I would like to show a post with a specific tag 'info' in front of all (even in front of sticky).

I thought I could just merge the queries in an array like this:

```
 $posts = array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'order' => $order_posts,  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ); 
$infoposts = array('tag' => 'info', 'post__in' => $sticky);

            query_posts ( array_merge( $infoposts, $posts ));
```

However this will only post the $infoposts array posts. How do I get both and then the posts with 'info' tag first?

How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_merge` merges your arrays together, var_dump the result of `array_merge( $infoposts, $posts )` to see what i mean.

AFAIK You'll need to do 2 separate queries, one for a sticky post and one for the other posts.

-- edit --

```
$sticky = get_posts($infoposts);
$rest = get_posts($posts);

$all = array_merge($sticky, $rest);

foreach ( $all as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); // this is important ?>

</ul>
```

tldr: use **get_posts** instead of query posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: OKay, that makes sense indeed. However when I query them both, $infoposts first and then $posts, they still get shown in the normal order. How would I query $infoposts first?